# calculation of no. of rows (data from csv) satisfying condition and also slower code

Tags: python, csv

```
    1       2       3       4       5
1   0.000   0.733   0.762   0.745   0.692
2   0.733   0.000   0.842   0.766   0.701
3   0.762   0.842   0.000   0.851   0.803
4   0.745   0.766   0.851   0.000   0.402
5   0.692   0.701   0.803   0.402   0.000
```

I am wrting a python code as follows:

```
import csv
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t0 = time.time()

count = 0

with open('test.csv','r') as infile:
    reader=csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    reader.next()
    for rows in reader:
        numbers = np.array([float(col) for col in rows])            
        numbersnz = numbers[numbers != 0.0]
        if (numbersnz[1:] >= 0.5):
        # **HERE I want to caculate how many rows (in the above csv file data) has 50% or more data points which are greater than 0.5. but I donot understand how to do it ??? please help.!!!** 

print time.time() - t0, "seconds"
```

this code is bit slower for 50000 * 50000 data ... so if any improvement in this... because and I am bit new to python I am unable to make faster code !!!

thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Small discrepancy: the code is checking if the columns are greater than or equal to 0.5, but the comment says you want to do the calculation based on the number of columns that are greater than (but not equal to) 0.5.

Comment: sorry for that ... it should only be greater than......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

50000 * 50000 numbers won't probably fit into your RAM, as @DavidAlber said.

But the following code should be fast enough and it keeps just the current row in the memory.

```
import csv
import time
import numpy as np

count = 0

with open('test.csv','r') as infile:
    reader=csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        rec = np.fromiter(row[1:], dtype=np.float32)
        if (rec > 0.5).sum() >= (len(rec) - 1) * 0.5:
            count += 1
```

Comment: ANOTHER HELP PLEASE !! WHAT IF I TRY TO EXTRACT THE ROW NUMBER FROM THE FIRST COLUMN WHICH SATISFY THOSE CONDITIONS BUT HERE IN THE ABOVE YOU HAVE TRUNCATED THAT.....AND ALSO I WANT TO FIND "how many rows have 60% or more data points which are greater than 0.6 and so on...." so where i should change in the code

Comment: @tanmay: 1. you can access `row[0]` within the loop. 2. Can you see those two `0.5` in the code? Change them according to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load a CSV file and compute the number of rows for which at least half of the columns contain a value greater than or equal to 0.5, this will do it:

```
a = np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter='\t', skiprows=1)
ncols = a.shape[1]-1
np.sum(np.sum(a[:,1:] >= 0.5, axis=1) >= ncols*0.5)
```

I expect this to be quite a bit faster than what is done in the question code.

This will work well for any array that fits in memory, but the array size mentioned in the question (50000 x 50000) does not (at least not the memory of a currently-typical machine). Therefore, this approach will not work unless the CSV files are split into smaller pieces that are handled as part of a loop.

Comment: ANOTHER HELP PLEASE !! WHAT IF I TRY TO EXTRACT THE ROW NUMBER FROM THE FIRST COLUMN WHICH SATISFY THOSE CONDITIONS BUT HERE IN YOUR CODE IT IS TRUNCATED.....AND ALSO I WANT TO FIND "how many rows have 60% or more data points which are greater than 0.6 and so on...." so where i should change in the code.... thanks

Comment: @tanmay The percent threshold is controlled by the second instance of `0.5` on the third line of the answer's code. As for extracting row number, it depends on what you want to do with it. For example, if you want an array of the rows that contribute to the count, the code would be modified in one way, but if you want the row number to somehow contribute in the calculation in Line 3, the code would be modified in a different way. Can you explain how you want to use the line numbers?

Comment: yep... you are true. I will plot row number (count of row) against the float values. well I have written them into a csv file. Thanks for your help !!